# How to iterate through a table rows and get the cell values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table

I am creating the below table dynamically using jQuery... After executing my code I get the table as below:

```
<table id="TableView" width="800" style="margin-left: 60px">
<tbody>
 <tr>
 <th>Module</th>
 <th>Message</th>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
 <td> car</td>
 <td>
  <input class="name" type="text">
 </td>
 <td>
<input class="id" type="hidden" value="5">
</td>
   </tr>
<tr class="item">
 <td> bus</td>
 <td>
  <input class="name" type="text">
 </td>
 <td>
<input class="id" type="hidden" value="9">
</td>
  </tr>
```

I used to iterate the table like this:

```
 $("tr.item").each(function() {
            var quantity1 = $this.find("input.name").val();
        var quantity2 = $this.find("input.id").val();

            });
```

By using the above query I am getting values of first row cells only... help me with jQuery that will iterate through the whole rows of the table and get the row cell values in `quantity1` and `quantity2`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`$(this)` instead of $this

```
$("tr.item").each(function() {
        var quantity1 = $(this).find("input.name").val(),
            quantity2 = $(this).find("input.id").val();
});
```

**[Proof_1](http://jsfiddle.net/3huUZ/)**

**[Proof_2](http://jsfiddle.net/jcJAQ/)**

Comment: I tried with $(this) also but I am getting only the first tr cell datas only

Comment: @Brittas see the fiddle's `console.log`, it gives you all value

Answer (score 11):

Looping through a table for each row and reading the 1st column value works by using JQuery and DOM logic.

```
var i = 0;
var t = document.getElementById('flex1');

$("#flex1 tr").each(function() {
    var val1 = $(t.rows[i].cells[0]).text();
    alert(val1) ;
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Hello every one thanks for the help below is the working code for my question

```
$("#TableView tr.item").each(function() { 
    var quantity1=$(this).find("input.name").val(); 
    var quantity2=$(this).find("input.id").val(); 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

**I got it and explained in below:**

//This table with two rows containing each row, one select in first td, and one input tags in second td and  second input in third td;

```
<table id="tableID" class="table table-condensed">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th><label>From Group</lable></th>
             <th><label>To Group</lable></th>
             <th><label>Level</lable></th>

           </tr>
       </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr id="rowCount">
             <td>
               <select >
                 <option value="">select</option>
                 <option value="G1">G1</option>
                 <option value="G2">G2</option>
                 <option value="G3">G3</option>
                 <option value="G4">G4</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="" value="" readonly="readonly" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value=""  readonly="readonly" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="rowCount">
          <td>
            <select >
              <option value="">select</option>
              <option value="G1">G1</option>
              <option value="G2">G2</option>
              <option value="G3">G3</option>
              <option value="G4">G4</option>
           </select>
         </td>
         <td>
           <input type="text" id="" value="" readonly="readonly" />
         </td>
         <td>
           <input type="text" value=""  readonly="readonly" />
         </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default generate-btn search-btn white-font border-6 no-border" id="saveDtls">Save</button>


//call on click of Save button;
 $('#saveDtls').click(function(event) {

  var TableData = []; //initialize array;                           
  var data=""; //empty var;

  //Here traverse and  read input/select values present in each td of each tr, ;
  $("table#tableID > tbody > tr").each(function(row, tr) {

     TableData[row]={
        "fromGroup":  $('td:eq(0) select',this).val(),
        "toGroup": $('td:eq(1) input',this).val(),
        "level": $('td:eq(2) input',this).val()
 };

  //Convert tableData array to JsonData
  data=JSON.stringify(TableData)
  //alert('data'+data); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry Mr.Quill, I am new to the Stackoverflow and this is first ans,  posted by me.

Comment: Below your post there is a ["edit" link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31088954/edit). Edit your post to improve the formatting, you can see how the answer will look while you edit it.

Answer (score 4):

You got your answer, but why iterate over the tr when you can go straight for the inputs? That way you can store them easier into an array and it reduce the number of CSS queries. Depends what you want to do of course, but for collecting data it is a more flexible approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/zqpgq/

```
var array = [];

$("tr.item input").each(function() {
    array.push({
        name: $(this).attr('class'),
        value: $(this).val()
    });
});

console.log(array);​
```