# How to databind multiple dropdownlists using loops

Tags: c#, jquery

I got a webform containing 10 asp.dropdownlists and 1 HTML table, each dropdownlist interact with a row of table cells.

These code work perfectly, but way too messy. I want to simplify it so it will be easier to read and maintenance.

### 1st code interact with dropdownlist (mat0, mat1,mat2....mat9) (c#)

Each dropdownlist share same data-source, value, and text. 
I use sqlAdapter+ sqlDataset + using() method for data binding。
Is there a way, like a loop through list of "dropdowns", in order to simplify the code.

### 2nd code interact with table rows (jQuery)

the table contain 3 columns * 10 rows.
column 3(totalPrice) = column 1(number)* column 2(price) (same row)
i use keyup(function  so sigma is calculate simultaneously.

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new 
SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                string buta = ("SELECT * FROM [Material] WHERE (([SupplierID] = @SupplierID) AND ([MaterialID] >= @MaterialID))");

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(buta, cnn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", Session["Gsuply"].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaterialID", Session["Gchoose"].ToString());
                    SqlDataAdapter dasupplier = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    dasupplier.Fill(ds, "dbo.Material");

                    mat0.DataSource = ds;
                    mat0.DataTextField = "MaterialName";
                    mat0.DataValueField = "MaterialID";
                    mat0.DataBind();

                    mat1.DataSource = ds;
                    mat1.DataTextField = "MaterialName";
                    mat1.DataValueField = "MaterialID";
                    mat1.DataBind();}}


<script>
      //Row 1 (number, price, totalPrice)
    $("#number, #price").keyup(function ()
    {
    var sigma = 1;
    $("#number, #price").each(function() {
        sigma *= Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#totalPrice').val(sigma);
        });

        //Row 2   (number1, price1, totalprice1)
    $("#number1, #price1").keyup(function ()
    {
    var sigma = 1;
    $("#number1, #price1").each(function() {
        sigma *= Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#totalPrice1').val(sigma);
        });
```

For c#, i expect some kind of loop for (i=0,i<=10,i++){mat[i].
For JQuery, i expect 1 JQuery only. (if possible)

Comment: If your `DropDownList` control's name is fixed like `mat0,mat1,.....matn` then you could use a loop of something like: `for(var i=0;i<YourLength;i++){var _ddl = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("mat"+i); _ddl.DataSource = ds; _ddl.DataTextField="MaterialName";_ddl.DateValueField="MaterialID";_ddl.DataBind(); }`

Comment: @vikscool works like a charm, thank you ;)  Any suggest for Jquery :D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this;

```
foreach(DropDownList list in Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
{
    //TODO: Your desired code
}
```

Comment: this works too, and much simpler.  Thank you. Any suggest for Jquery :D?

Comment: @Max You can check this question, has similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434711/how-to-iterate-through-a-table-rows-and-get-the-cell-values-using-jquery/25171001