# How to iterate over rows of nth unnamed table

Tags: jquery, cheerio

I'm trying to use Cheerio (similar to jQuery) to manipulate a HTML page that looks something like this:

```
<TABLE>
<!--- table body -->
</TABLE>
<!-- more html -->
<TABLE>
<!--- another table body -->
</TABLE>
<!-- more html -->
<TABLE>
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD>Column 1 value</TD>
      <!-- similar cols 2-5 -->
    </TR>
    <!-- more rows -->
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
<!-- rest of page -->
```

That is, there are three TABLE elements on that page, none of whom have an id. I need the third one. I just want to iterate over the rows in the table and extract the first, third, and fifth cells in each row.

Should be simple, right? But I can't figure out even how to iterate over the rows.

```
const $ = Cheerio.load(html);
const third = $($("table").get(2));
third.find("tr").each((i, e) => {
  console.log(String(i));
})
```

This produces no output.

If I log `third.html()` that writes the html of the correct table. But I can't even so much as count the number of rows in it, let alone drill down to the table cells. I've looked at [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891357/how-to-iterate-a-table-rows-with-jquery-and-access-some-cell-values) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434711/how-to-iterate-through-a-table-rows-and-get-the-cell-values-using-jquery) answers, but they all base it off a single selector from the root. I don't really understand what data type `third` is, or how to manipulate it.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Edited post to add skeleton html.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  The output is a single `0`, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheerio works (more or less) the same way as jQuery does. So, if you aren't sure how to do something in Cheerio, I'd recommend looking at the jQuery docs. In any case: try this:

```
$('table').eq(2).find("tr").each(function(i, row){
    console.log($(this).find('td').eq(0).html());
    console.log($(this).find('td').eq(2).html())
    console.log($(this).find('td').eq(4).html())
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand it from the jQuery docs either. But this worked :)